# Unable to login to windows 7 account

Tags: windows-7

Up until recently i was able to login to my work machine. One day all of a sudden me nor anyone on the domain is able to login to the machine. It says incorrect username and password or it doesn't recognize we are part of the domain or something.

Comment: Have a Domain Administrator check and make sure that the user accounts haven't expired. Note that you might get more complete assistance if you provide additional information and ask in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: This really is only something your IT Administrator can solve.  If you happen to be that IT Administrator, based on the limited information you have provided, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Our domain admin passed away recently and we are trying to handle issues temp by ourself. I am not really sure what additional details I can provide or where I can start looking to fix the issue.

Comment: Network passwords are almost always set to expire in a set time, perhaps a month. Either you'll need to hire a new network IT admin and hope s/he can find the Administrator password, or someone else in IT might be able to help... or you'll need a lot of reinstallation. Perhaps a senior official of the organization has the needed information.

Comment: At the very least [edit] your question and provide actual word for word messages you are seeing, or preferably screenshots too. “Doesn’t recognize we are part of the domain or something,” doesn’t tell us anything. Windows gives specific messages that might not mean anything to you, but mean everything to others.

Comment: Your company needs to hire a new IT professional or contract out for support services. I'm sorry to hear your admin passed away, but it is still your company's responsibility to make sure the systems work and to make provision for that.